# Your project does not have access to this feature (403)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have receive the mail from google like

> Great news! We’ve received your request to join the Google Analytics
>   Account Setup and Configuration APIs Beta and your project has been
>   whitelisted for access. These APIs allow you to programmatically
>   create and edit properties, views, and goals.

But when I am wondering to access the management api here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.profiles.insert?accountId=83303713&webPropertyId=UA-83303713-1&_h=3&resource=%257B%250A%257D&

I am getting the same error like

> "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
>       "message": "Your project does not have access to this feature."    }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Your project does not have access
>   to this feature."  }

what else is missing?

Comment: you should have been added to a Google Group as well.  Post a message in there someone should be able to help.   The project you applied with "should" have access by now.

Comment: I am not getting if I applied for "should" have access now. I have submitted the form with all the required fields. but why still this error? anyways thanks for your help. :)

Comment: There is an error because you don't have access.   If you got an email from them that you have been accepted into the beta program then you should have access.   Part of the beta program includes a Google Group you should ask in there why your access isn't working.  No one here can help you.  This is only something that Google can fix.

Comment: You are not calling the API from your project. You are calling it from the API explorer, which is different project than the one you have whitelisted. Read the warning message above the API explorer in the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert#try-it)

Comment: Thanks Matt for the response. I got your point but how can I test this call? even not able to do it in postman

Comment: Curious, were you able to come up with a solution for this problem? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: @SuperKevin I had the same, let's stay in touch if any of us will find solution